# input a non-numeric value to a float

Tags: c++, char, cout, cin

I have this simple code where I input values to two float variables and they get displayed. What I am not able to understand is what happens if I give my input as non numeric. Like when I input 'a'( without ' '), a strange number gets generated- 2.69525+0323.21398e=039. How and why is this number generated?

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
    float x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<x<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, how can I stop someone from entering a non-numeric value? I thought of storing the number in an array,iterating through it and using isdigit(), also a case for seeing if a decimal point appears and it should only appear once but this seems a not so good approach. Any better approach?

Comment: The input fails, which you would know if you checked the return value, and the variables are left with whatever random uninitialized value they had when you declared them.

Comment: That is the random values `x` and `y` are initialized with. That's why you should always initialize your variables.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't know if it's a really stupid question but how do I check the value returned by main() ?

Answer (score 4):

`- 2.69525+0323.21398e=039` is actuall two strange numbers without a space between them.

They are most likely the random values that were in `x` & `y` to start with.  The `cin` failed, so they were unchanged.

#### How can I stop someone from entering a non-numeric value?

- Yell at them and threaten no dessert.  - or -
- import the values as strings, verfiy them as numbers, and then convert them to floats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I get the value entered in a char array, verify them as number using isdigit()? But what should I do of the decimal point in between? Please elaborate the procedure a little. I am not very sure.